# Auto adjust position height based on other panels height Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So, i am pretty new to programming, and i've stumbled into this problem: i have some collapsible panels which are auto positioned beautifully, but they are on the same row: when i open a panel, all under side panel translate towards the bottom. I want them to readjust their height position to where they were before. I'm using Boostrap Sas 3. An image will be more clear

What appens now:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0lHu.png)
What i want to happen:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOiQd.png)

My code:

```
<div class='form-group'>
  <label class='control-label col-sm-3'>Belongs to:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-bottom: 7px">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px">
              <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom:0px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="2" /> org
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body collapse" id="collapse2" style="padding: 5px">
                  <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom:0px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="1" />
                    sub
                  </label><br>
                  <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom:0px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="2" />
                    sub2
                  </label><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-bottom: 7px">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px">
              <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom:0px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="3" /> org2
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body collapse" id="collapse3" style="padding: 5px">
                  <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom:0px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="3" />
                    SubTes
                  </label><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-bottom: 7px">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px">
              <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom:0px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="4" /> org3
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body collapse" id="collapse4" style="padding: 5px">
                  <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom:0px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="4" />
                    SubTest
                  </label><br>
                  <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom:0px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="5" />
                    subga
                  </label><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-bottom: 7px">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px">
              <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse5" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom:0px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="5" /> gar
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body collapse" id="collapse5" style="padding: 5px">
                  <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom:0px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="6" />
                    gargag
                  </label><br>
                  <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom:0px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="7" />
                    graga
                  </label><br>
                  <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom:0px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="" value="8" />
                    gara
                  </label><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-bottom: 7px">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px">
              <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse6" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom:0px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="6" /> gragag
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body collapse" id="collapse6" style="padding: 5px">
                  <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom:0px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="9" />
                    gragagarg
                  </label><br>
                  <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom:0px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="10" />
                    argga
                  </label><br>
                  <label style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom:0px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="" value="11" />
                    ragrg
                  </label><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out [card columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns)